# My largest bound violation is CPLEX showing in e^6 range. What does it indicates? But the solutions are within my expectations

Tags: optimization, resultset, cplex, convex, non-convex

[image]
The solution tab of my problem is as shown above.  How can I interpret the quality of my model . Solutions are upto my expectations but the maximum bound infeasibility shows a larger value.nHow can I reduce the bound violation

Comment: The fact that you mention the 'solution tab' suggests that you are using CPLEX & OPL Studio. Did you name any of your constraints? If you do, then I think that by default CPLEX will relax them if the problem is infeasible. Personally I **really** dislike this 'feature'. Check the solution in detail and check if it is a real solution or not, as it may be CPLEX's guess at how to make the problem feasible by relaxing stuff.

Comment: Yes l have named my constraints.There is some mismatch for the solution according to my problem.But when taking it into overall all the constraints are satisfying.Is n't it a real solution.Sir  for a problem with so many constraints is it possible to give the feasible solution without relaxation.I think some relaxations are mandatory for getting the results

Comment: If your problem is over-constrained so that you need some relaxations to find a solution, then you are **far** better off thinking about those relaxations yourself and designing your own explicit model for that, e.g. adding some explicit slack variables in some constraints, and penalising non-zero values of those slack variables in your objective. At least then you are in control of what gets relaxed, how much relaxation is allowed in each constraint, which order the relaxations happen, etc. Simply relying on CPLEX to make arbitrary relaxations without problem knowledge is not great.